# How to replace convert command with magick.exe for this command?

Tags: imagemagick

The command below works using the "convert" command.  But I get the error shown when I try using the magick.exe command.  How can I execute this command using magick.exe?   I'm using IM 7.1.0.

magick $jpgfile -font Arial -pointsize 60 -fill lightblue -quality 100  -gravity southeast `
-auto-orient -annotate +80+50 %[exif:DateTimeOriginal] $jpgfile

magick.exe: unknown image property "%[exif:DateTimeOriginal]" @ warning/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/4209.

Comment: You have to install Imagemagick 7 to use "magick". Convert is for Imagemagick 6 and does not have the magick command.

Comment: I'm using IM 7.1.0.

Comment: On what OS?  If Windows, then try magick.exe

Comment: Sorry, I see your error message now.  Post an example image that has issues and I will check on my Imagemagick 7.

Comment: $jpgfile is usually the way you use a variable in Unix and not on Windows. Are you on Linux or Windows or Mac? If on Linux, put double quotes about the %[exif:....]"

Comment: The above command works using the older "convert" IM command.  This is Windows 10, in a PowerShell script.

Comment: Sorry, I am not a Windows users and do not know the syntax for powershell. If you post your image, I can test on my Mac with your command. But I suspect your install of IM 7 is bad. "magick.exe" or "magick" should work depending upon your OS. What do you get from `magick.exe -version` or `magick -version`? Do you get the version and list of delegates or do you get an error message?

Comment: PS C:\Users\bernie> magick -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-27 Q16-HDRI x64 2022-03-05 

There is nothing wrong with the installation of ImagicMagick.  There seems to be a difference in syntax between convert.exe and magick.exe.  That was what I was asking about.  Tell me if this command works for you:


magick myfile.jpg -font Arial -pointsize 60 -fill lightblue -quality 100 -gravity southeast ` -auto-orient -annotate +80+50 %[exif:DateTimeOriginal] $myfile.jpg

Comment: I see on the Imagemagick forum that you found that it worked for you directly and that the issue is Powershell. So I guess this is closed.

Comment: Yes, it works from the command line.  I thought since I upgraded IM and changed nothing else there was a syntax issue.  Thanks for your help anyway.